# Operation betwenn two date / datetime

Tags: apex, date, datetime

In a condition, I had to make a substraction between two datetime and check how many days a separating the two datetime like that :

```
if(datetime2 - datetime2 > 5){
   //do something
}
```

Of course this syntax does not work, I want to know what syntax to use for doing something like this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can get `date` part of `datetime` for ech date, and the  compare days between two dates be means of `daysBetween` method. all list of methods present in `Date` class can be read [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_date.htm)

```
Date date1 = datetime1.date();
Date date2 = datetime2.date();
if(date2.daysBetween(date1) > 5){
    //do something
}
```

Comment: One thing to be aware of with this approach is that the result can be off by a day (one day at most) depending on your locale and how `datetime1` and `datetime2` are initialized. I ran into a similar issue within the past week where `DateTimet testDT = Date.Today(); System.debug(testDT.date());` would print yesterday's date in the debug log because assigning a `Date` to a `DateTime` gives the resulting `time` component a value of `00:00:00`, and does not take locale into account. `date()` does take locale into account, and if you're in a UTC-x locale, midnight today - anything = yesterday

Comment: @DerekF how did figured out that problem?

Comment: I'd like to say it was all due to skill and experience, but there was probably some luck involved too. I was running through my standard debugging procedure (start where the error occurs, inspect data. If data isn't what I expect it to be, go to where that data is generated/passed from. Repeat until I find the source) and noticed that `DateTime.date()` was giving me an unexpected value. I looked at the documentation for `date()` and saw it mentioned using the user's locale. I ran some simple anonymous apex to confirm my suspicion, and to confirm that `dateGMT()` gave me the result I wanted.